# Extremely mild punishments for academic misconduct

Tags: ethics

After looking at [My professor is rigging data and plagiarizing. What can I do?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31265/my-professor-is-rigging-data-and-plagiarizing-what-can-i-do), I read through some of the [case reports of the Committee on Publication Ethics (COPE)](http://publicationethics.org/cases) and I noticed that punishments seem to be very light. When COPE receives a case, sometimes an attempt is made to contact the institution, and then the institution does nothing: perhaps the wrongdoer is too politically powerful, or the institution doesn't have any will to act. Sometimes the investigation simply fizzles out after nobody bothers to look at the lab journals, even though the lab journals presumably exist. Sometimes the journal is told how to avoid such problems in the future, but no punishments are forthcoming for the existing case.

This is very different from what I believed before - that if someone did decide to falsify/steal data, their employment would be terminated, and nobody would ever want to associate with them again.

So my question is: *where is the discrepancy between how I perceive the consequences of academic misconduct, and what COPE reports as actual cases?* Is it perhaps because most of the misconduct cases are from no-name departments and journals that do not care about their reputation? Or are my impressions of the consequences of misconduct incorrect?

In fact, I have experienced this on my own: one non-mathematics professor at my school took my mathematics manuscript, added his graduate students as coauthors despite their having no relation to the work, and tried to submit it to a journal. I don't care about this specific publication, as it is so worthless that I prefer it to be rejected as to not be associated with me. The professor thinks it is significant only because he knows nothing of mathematics. But it does make me question the kind of integrity I assumed of academics. He is a chair professor at a top10 university, and his (non-mathematics, science) department is very well-respected, so brand name is not the cause here.

Comment: I scanned some of the COPE "case closed" reports. All I have read are anonymised. How do you know the wrongdoers did not get punishments?

Comment: Punishments for wrongdoing are not always mild, as you suggest. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haruko_Obokata http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshiki_Sasai and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6n_scandal and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_misconduct

Comment: I'm not sure how to clarify. My question is: COPE reports mild punishments. I think the general attitude is that punishments are generally harsh. Why is there a discrepancy between the COPE cases and the general attitude?

Comment: If anyone sees a way to edit the question to be clearer, feel free to modify it however you like. I think my perspective on its clarity is skewed heavily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The situation you describe in your last paragraph does not sound like business as usual at all: on the contrary, it sounds so bizarre that I am having trouble picturing it taking place.  (This is at a top 10 university *in the US*??)  I suppose there must be more to the story, but: granting what you say, indeed this professor does not have the right to publish the paper without your permission.  Especially if you think the work is not valuable enough to be published, you should absolutely contact the journal ASAP to withdraw the paper.

Unfortunately I suspect that you're correct that punishments for faculty who plagiarize or commit other forms of academic misconduct are distressingly light, in particular for many of the reasons that you suggest.  If someone is caught intentionally falsifying data or -- the horror, the horror -- submitting a knowingly false proof, then the community as a whole is going to feel victimized and take some steps to ostracize or ban this faculty member.  However, if it's a case of stealing material from a student: it pains me to say this, but often the easy course is to slap the faculty member on the wrist and look out to be sure that this behavior is not repeated in the near future.

I don't know what other people are doing, and I have heard more stories of faculty skullduggery on this site than in the rest of my life combined.  But for whatever it's worth, 99.9% of all faculty members I've ever met would sooner break into my office and steal my computer than steal a paper from a student.  If the trends are different in other fields and/or other parts of the world (and I think they must be, to an extent), I am really sorry to hear that.  Academia without academic integrity is one of the most hollow pursuits I can imagine.

Comment: He does not realize he is doing anything wrong (although I obviously disagree), but I'm not going to bring anything up. His motivation seems only to help his graduate students along. He himself is involved with the paper a bit, but not to the point where he would be considered a coauthor. Since I don't think the paper will be accepted anywhere, I am happy to let the editor dash his dreams instead of myself. And indeed, this is a top10 US university.

Comment: His policy seems to be "spread coauthorship around", which might be fine in his field; I'm not familiar with it. I don't think he is a bad sort. Although his actions here are clearly misconduct, they aren't motivated by self-gain. I, too, believe that he would rather do anything than steal a student's paper for himself, but as to reassigning credit...

Comment: Pete: until my stints as Dir Grad Studies in Math, I, too, was blithely unaware of faculty malfeasance, especially toward students. However, during those stressful epochs, a distressing number of cases were brought to my attention. In all cases, the faculty involved faced no consequences, and it was rationalized-away by the people with both information and power. Now being again-blissfully _out_ of those loops, I again see nothing of the sort. Thus, I conclude that it is happening all the time, but most of us are not witnesses.

Comment: That last para should be put somewhere prominent on the site, perhaps in a "Quotable Quotes" section. Having said that, I think that your assumption about 99.9% of faculty is way too optimistic. I think Math, for a variety of reasons, does not reward abusive behavior by faculty like some other fields do, but I'm sure it still happens. I think most of the faculty on this site are nice people who are here trying to help. But lots of people are not nice, and it is not always clear who isn't nice. Especially if you don't happen to be in a position where they can hurt you. One should remember that.

Comment: @Feij: I am a bit confused as to how someone who "knows nothing of mathematics" got involved with a math paper.  Whether he would be considered a coauthor is something that the two of you should work out together.  Adding the names of people (especially students, who are not PIs on a grant) who had no involvement in the paper is not fine in any academic field.  Also, there are a lot of math journals out there which will publish virtually any paper which is sent to them, especially if payment is received.  Why are you letting this bad behavior stand?

Comment: @paul: I am really sorry to hear that.  This behavior must be more common than I know: that's the only rational response.

Comment: I think he is too respectable to be taken in by predatory journals, and the paper is successfully failing to be accepted to wherever he is submitting it to. If this failure continues any longer, I may have to celebrate.

Comment: The reason I am doing nothing is because there is no benefit in it to me, and potentially a lot of harm. His bad behavior may be isolated to this specific instance of mathematics; he has a good reputation in his field. Since I doubt there will be any positive outcomes for him, me, or anyone else, and there doesn't seem to be malicious intent, I'm comfortable to let the matter slide. If I was worried, I would first of all request my name removed from the manuscript.

Comment: One good thing that would come from this is not to have the making the rounds of the mathematical community with your name on it.  You have said that anyone who knows something about mathematics would know that the paper is not publishable.  So all of the referees of this stinker now think this about you?

Comment: Also you are allowing the community to waste its time on a paper that if accepted, you would withdraw your name from, which might (and should, according to what you said) result in the paper not being published. Being a member of a professional community includes upholding community standards.  There is a bit of irony here in that I see a *de facto* answer to your question.

Comment: Yes, I now see your reasoning. I should have my name removed from the manuscript, and will think about how to request that from the professor tactfully.

Comment: @Feij: Tactfully sounds good.  I wish you the best of luck.