# I am in search of a tool to check documents and generate a plagiarism report

Tags: publications, phd, computer-science

I'm wrapping up a survey paper. During the writing process, I was in a rush and used Quillbot for rephrasing without noting down the specific sections. I initially just wanted to complete it and send it to my advisor. Now, as I'm considering publication, I want to ensure there's no plagiarism and identify where I might have used the tool. Is there any free tool to check for potential plagiarism? I did not use the tool to rephrase others' work. I used the tool to check my text in terms of grammar and cohesion. The Grammarly tool also does the same thing, but the premium version is expensive, so I used another tool. Grammarly-corrected sentences do not count as plagiarism.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a reasonable question about at morally suspect process.

Comment: @EthanBolker I'm guessing they are because people are seeing this as a question about how to get away with a behavior they see as unethical.

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes, I can see that.

Comment: @EthanBolker While Bryan Krause is probably right, I am voting based on "does not show research effort."

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/185808/online-checker-for-plagiarism-how-accurate-are-they

Comment: If an answer does not contain a **free tool to check for potential plagiarism** then I will flag it as not an answer.

Comment: The OP is asking for a tool to identify AI generated content though. Those don't really exist (despite what companies are willing to sell you). On top of that, both Grammarly and Quillbot appear to have free versions of their plagiarism checkers - I'm not sure how one could miss that. This seems like an XY problem.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you know there is plagiarism and are looking for confirmation that you won't get caught... For what it's worth, there is no reliable way to identify AI generated content at this time.

Did you use the tool to edit sections of your text? Or did you use it to "rephrase" other's work in order to incorporate it into your paper?

In the first case, depending on journal policy, you can just cite the tool. In the second case, consider rewriting the paper.

Answer (score 2):

Go back to your original text - you do still have that version, of course.

Now study the changes your artificially intelligent assistant suggested. Think about how they improved the presentation. Edit again yourself, to make sure that the text says what you actually mean, not what the statistics from the AIs large language model "thought" you meant.

You can still edit your paper that way even if you don't have the original. Pretend it's something you have been given to read and check for sense.

Learn from this experience how to make those improvements yourself. And learn not to rush so you are not tempted to take dicey shortcuts.

In this particular instance, what you have done is probably not plagiarism if in fact the ideas were all yours (or acknowledged). Tell your advisor what you did and ask them what you should do next.